# I am getting error when using hook in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can some explain what these two line is used for in the `application.html.haml` file. I am using Rails 6

```
= hook(:stylesheet_includes, self) do
#{yield :stylesheet_includes}
```

I am getting the following error

```
undefined method `hook' for #<#<Class:0x000000000bb090b8>:0x0000000007886f10>
```

Comment: Where is that `hook` method supposed to be coming from? That looks to be a haml template, but I rummaged around on the interwhozits a bit and couldn't find a haml method called `hook`.

Comment: Are you using fat_free_crm?

Comment: Yes, I am using fat_free_crm.